# Código javascript para generar inputs

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas a todos, tengo un archivo el cual pide el numero de paradas (estados o municipios) de una ruta el cual lo paso al segundo archivo y con un while pongo los lugares de paradas y les creo un boton por cada parada el cual al dar clic cree un input text estatico si me sale pero como hago para generar codigo script para cada boton porque deben ser con diferente id y name adjunto el codigo

Script

```
   var totalPoints = 0;

        function AddNewPoint() {
            totalPoints = totalPoints + 1;
            var pointElem = document.getElementById('Waypoint');
            if (totalPoints == 1) {
                pointElem.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                // btnAddWaypoint.innerHTML = "Nuevo punto";
                var divAllPoints = document.getElementById('AllPoints');
                var nextPoint = pointElem.cloneNode(true);
                // nextPoint.children[0].textContent = "Nuevo punto:";
                nextPoint.children[0].value = "";
                divAllPoints.appendChild(nextPoint);
            }
        };

    function DeletePoint(control) {
      totalPoints = totalPoints - 1;
      var divToDelete = control.parentNode;
      var divAllPoints = document.getElementById('AllPoints');
        divAllPoints.removeChild(divToDelete);
    };
```

Con esta linea tomo el numero de paradas

```
$numeroEscalas = $_POST['numeroEscalas'];
```

y este codigo html donde genero los input (estaticos)

```
   <div id="AllPoint">
          <div id="Waypoints" style="display:none">

           Lugar de visita <input type="text" name="puntosDestino[]" class="input">
            <button class="button btn btn-warning" onclick="DeletePoints(this)">X</button>   

          </div>
      </div>
```

mi duda es si tengo N paradas como generar el script para cada boton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi consejo es que metas el código que quieres clonar dentro de un elemento `<script type="text/template" id="tpl_waypoint">`. Y luego lee el contenido con `document.getElementById("tpl_waypoint").innerHTML`.

Dentro metes el `<div>` pero en vez de ponerle directamente un `id="waypoints"` le pones `id="{{id}}" class="waypoint"` y luego reemplazas `{{id}}` por el id que le quieras dar a cada uno. Una vez hecho esto añades el `<div>` al DOM.

Puedes utilizar un *template engine* para ello; te ahorrará mucho tiempo. Yo suelo usar el que viene con [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template) que es bastante sencillo y ligero.

Respecto a los botones, no les des a cada uno un id diferente, dale una clase. Luego, utiliza la función `on()` de jQuery para manejar eventos de elementos que todavía no existen:

`$(document).on(".waypoint .btn-eliminar", "click", function () { ... });`

La ventaja de `on()` es que funcionará con botones que añadas más tarde dinámicamente, siempre que utilices el selector CSS adecuado.

Y dentro de la función que maneja el evento, sacas el id del waypoint así:

`var id = $(this).closest(".waypoint").attr("id");`

Espero que te sirva. Necesitas una o dos librerías externas, pero creo que vale la pena.